# Skip https on one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

I have a website and now i want to disable https for one page. I have tried quite some htaccess codes but can't seem to get it to work.

My htaccess code is as follows:

```
# BEGIN custom php.ini PHP54
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home3/jirayer/public_html
</IfModule>
# END custom php.ini

## Disable Framing of Website - Security Fix ##
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
## Disable Framing of Website - Security Fix ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fipe.net/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


## Disable Folder Browsing ##
Options -Indexes
## Disable Folder Browsing ##
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^index.html(.*)$ https://www.fipe.net/$1 [r=301,nc]
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.fipe.net
```

I want to skip the page whatmyip.html from the https

Answer (score 0):

use the following condition bellow "RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80" line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/whatmyip.html
```

It excludes the /whatmyip.html url fromt  the  RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your htaccess. That solves the issue

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^/whatmyip.html(.*)$ http://www.<your domain>.com/whatmyip.html$1 [R,L]
```